# Pick the last sequence and deploy a new resource with next sequence azure powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I am trying to automate the azure resource deployment using powershell.

Requirments : In a particular resource group(RG), there are multiple VMs. the naming convention are like,

XXX-XX-X-XXXXXX-VM-01,

XXX-XX-X-XXXXXX-VM-02,

XXX-XX-X-XXXXXX-VM-03.

I am trying to create a script which will look for the last sequence(is this case 03) and deploy the next VM  with next sequence(here it should be 04).

I have the script to deploy the VM using powershell. Need help to fix the sequence logic.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar requirement and have been working on down the following route. In my case the numeric value is on the third element of the name,  but I put in your value in hope this works for you.

```
# I created an Array to hold the values returned from splitting the Name string.
$CurrentVal = @()

# Used a ForEach loop to Get VM in required Resource Group 
ForEach ($vmName in (Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName <resourcegroupName>).Name){
   # Convert to Decimal the Split String
   $vmNum = [Decimal]($vmName.split('-')[5])
   #Add to the Array
   $CurrentVal = $Currentval + $vmNum
 } 

#Then got the value.
$nextVal = ($Currentval | measure -maximum).Maximum + 1
```

With the returned value, I can then ceate the next VM.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

As a general reusable solution:

```
function Get-NextString {
    param ([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)][String]$InputObject)
    begin {
        $Last, $Name = $Null
    }
    process {
        $Name, $Sequence = $_ -Split '(?=\d*$)', 2
        if ([int]$Sequence -gt $Last) { $Last = $Sequence }
    }
    end {
        $Name + (1 + $Last).ToString("D$($Last.Length)")
    }
}
```

**usage:**

```
$List =
'XXX-XX-X-XXXXXX-VM-01',
'XXX-XX-X-XXXXXX-VM-02',
'XXX-XX-X-XXXXXX-VM-03'

$List |Get-NextString
XXX-XX-X-XXXXXX-VM-04
```

**Explanations:**

- `param ([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)][String]$InputObject)` accepts (multiple) strings from the pipeline, each string is processed as `$_`, the current item
- For the `begin`, `process` and `end` blocks, read [about Functions Advanced Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods)
- `$Name, $Sequence = $_ -Split '(?=\d*$)', 2` splits the current sting in the prefix (`$name`) and the sequence number. See also: [Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)
- `if ([int]$Sequence -gt $Last) { $Last = $Sequence }` catch the highest number

  - The `[int]` in front of the `$Sequence` will force an numeric comparison
- `$Name + (1 + $Last).ToString("D$($Last.Length)")` outputs the new string.

  - `(1 + $Last)` increase the `$Last` number with 1. Note that the `$Last` string will be automatically cast to an integer as the operant at the left hand side of the operator is an integer (`1`).
  - `ToString("D$($Last.Length)")` will format the sequence to the same number of digits as contained by `$Last`, see also: [Pad a Number with Leading Zeros](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-pad-a-number-with-leading-zeros)